# How to create a shell account and restrict users to their home folder

Tags: server, 13.04, permissions, webserver

I was wondering how in Ubuntu Server 13.04, how to limit a user to be able to only access their home folder and NOTHING else on the server.

Thanks,
Stephen

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs

Comment: You can not as they need to access many things in the system, such as /bin/bash. You can restrict users with jails or Apparmor. I suggest apparmor see - http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9799756&postcount=5 There are many alternates, guest accounts, etc, but IMO, on Ubuntu, apparmor is easiest and most secure.